# Edit rejected for changing too much of the original post on link only answer

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, link-only-answers, jsfiddle

I recently encountered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010555/d3-drag-behavior-glitch-when-dragging-svg-elements/15945191#15945191) link only answer and edited it to include the content from the jsfiddle link. The [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1900335) was rejected however (by a ratio of 3:2).

What is the correct proceedure for approaching such answers? Initially, I was going to flag it as NAA but the author had gone to the trouble of coding up a solution and I didn't want this to be lost hence the edit.

Consequently, how did this bypass the check that jsfiddle links need to be accompanied by code in the first place?

Comment: "Consequently, how did this bypass the check that jsfiddle links need to be accompanied by code in the first place?" The `<>` occurring immediately after the link.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sneaky, but what was the point in their going to the effort to code the jsfiddle if they were too lazy to copy and paste the code over.

Comment: Precisely. I don't understand these people.

Comment: @Ren ...And going through the bother of actively circumventing the anti-jsfiddle-only-filter. Boggles the mind. They're doing it [here too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943292/how-to-drag-svg-group-using-d3js-drag-behavior).

Comment: @J. Steen: And then there's [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15924980/revisions) (and my comment on that question). I opened the fiddle link hours later only to find that indeed, the code given in the question completely contradicted the parenthetical remark that I removed.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Like I said - boggles the mind. The score-pattern on the person's answers and questions is also somewhat suspect, but could just be a coincidence, of course. Not to mention one of their questions has been answered by a person with the same username.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Do you think it is worth submitting the edit suggestion again or should I just flag it?

Comment: @Ren They've been cautioned in comments and still haven't reacted. I'd say flag, but I'm more unforgiving that way.

Comment: @Ren Mind if I just make that edit? No need for review then.

Comment: @Bart could you? Cheers :)

Comment: @Ren Done. Sorry for the rep, but thanks for the work.

Comment: @Bart I don't really mind the rep. It's the fact it got rejected that bothers me :(

Comment: Wait what? Has the answer been deleted?

Comment: @Bart looks like it :S

Comment: mod-deleted, to be exact. After it is no longer a link-only answer. I don't have the rep to undelete, though.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Sorry to ping you, but could you have a look at the now deleted answer? I guess that was still a result of link-only flags?

Comment: @Bart: Yeah it was. The flag came shortly before your edit. It's back up now.